# How can I use my laptop like an external hdd with use of any cable

Tags: networking, hard-drive, laptop

I want to use my laptop like an external hard drive.

How can I completely access my laptop's storage on another computer with the help of any cable?

Can we mount a particular partition of the laptop on another PC?

Comment: [Actually you could do it with network cables](http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Two-Computers-Together-with-an-Ethernet-Cable). why do you want to do this?

Comment: As a practical i wanna do this

Comment: "Can you" and "How" are two different questions.  @Moab's comment addresses "can you".  "How" would be an overly broad question, even if you narrow it down with OS and hardware specs.

Comment: As a practical _joke_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your laptop is a Mac, you can put your system bus into [Target Disk Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target_Disk_Mode), allowing you to effectively use your laptop as a FireWire or Thunderbolt interface for the internal storage device (HDD or SSD).

If the laptop is a PC, you do not have this option. You must either boot the machine into an operating system and share the drive using a network-based protocol over any network interface, or use something like a [USB Bridge Cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZHYYQQ).

Unfortunately for PCs, this means it's usually just easiest to yank out the internal drive and connect it to a USB interface if you need to bypass the laptop hardware for file recovery.

Comment: odds are its not a Mac, as Mac users are a bit more savvy than the question reveals.

Comment: @Moab I'm well aware, just like to be thorough.